# Setting up Redis in Dotnet 6 Project

Tags: .net, redis

I added the Redis library in my Dotnet 6 project. everything is setup well, but Redis cannot connect. with this error:
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: 'It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s).
The problem is on the server path.

```
// Add Redis cache service
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = "localhost:44398";
});
```

my launchSetting.json is:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:65528",
      "sslPort": 44398
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "RT.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7299;http://localhost:5299",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
  }
}
```

and I'm launching with IIS Express.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be using port 44398 for iis, but also using that for the redis port... so: what is the redis port here? Is redis running in a container? Do we have a redis server here?

Comment: Tnx, that was the problem